# Topology of local uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-spaces

Let X be a topological space and Y a uniform space. Does there exist a topology of local uniform convergence on $Y^X$?

Comment: What is the 'topology of local uniform convergence' meant to be?

Comment: Maybe this helps: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence